# Read value from tooltip text

Tags: c#, asp.net

I use the tooltip to show timespan value and would like to be able to read that value again.

it is possible to read the value of a tooltip?

if yes how?

Comment: You can use control1.tooltip to read value of tooltip

Comment: yes i works thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

very simple:

myButton = (Button)Page.FindControl(btnName);

string ToolTipText = myButton.ToolTip;

Comment: I didn't understand, posting answer yourself and accepting it after accepting another answer?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `control1.tooltip` to read value of tooltip

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11713218)

Comment: @coded what makes you think this answer (albeit low-quality) is not an answer?

Comment: You need to explain what does the functionality do in an answer. Simply posting the code is not a good enough answer.

Comment: If it helped the topic starter, my guess is that it's a good enough answer :)

Comment: @coded "not a good answer" != "not an answer". Go read some [meta] questions on "not an answer" and be enlightened.

Comment: @L-Three an answer that helped the OP doesn't necessarily have to be a good answer. In fact it's pretty bad in its current form. But that doesn't make it "not an answer".

Comment: @Codecaster I understand and agree, that's why I said 'good enough', because it helped topic starter and I suppose that's like the whole idea of stack overflow :)